# MVC4 Area route: action methods on default controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 app with a Companies Area.

Given file structure:

```
Areas   
\
  Companies
    \
     Controllers
       |
       DefaultController (Contains Index and Edit actions)
       TestController (Contains Index and Test action)
```

I want my URL's to be like:

- /Companies
- /Companies/Edit
- /Companies/Test
- /Companies/Test/Test

My route is set like like in my CompaniesAreaRegistration class.

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "Companies_default",
    url: "Companies/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Results:

- /Companies - Works
- /Companies/Edit - 404
- /Companies/Default/Edit - Works
- /Companies/Test - Works
- /Companies/Test/Test - Works

How can I access my DefaultController.Edit() action without "Default" in the URL?

**Update**

Based on Brad's answer, I know I can hard code the paths like this and it will work. I was really hoping for more of an automatic solution. I don't know how many actions I will end up having on some Area's default controllers. I don't want to have to create a new route for every one.

This is the default route added as part of the MVC template in the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

If I have an action on the HomeController called "Test", I can hit that action using the URL /Test. I don't have to add a new route with the URL like "/Test/{id}" in order for this to work. It appears to ignore the {controller} part of the URL and use the default controller configuration.

Why does this behavior change when you do it in an Area?

The Area route is exactly the same as the Default route, except for the "Companies/" prefix to the URL.

As a test, I changed my Default route URL to `url: "Example/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and I am *still* able to access HomeController.Test() by at the URL /Example/Test.

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "Companies_Edit",
    url: "Companies/Edit/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Remember parameters are filled left-to-right (can't skip over `{controller}` and only populate `{action}`. If you want `{controller}` to be assumed, specify it in the `defaults`)

Comment: I just wanted to add that this should be added to the route table, not replace the existing route table.  Also, when added, it should be above the default route you are currently using as it is more 'specific' of a route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd consider this kind of a workaround. New routes aren't needed in the non-Areas default controllers to get this to work. The Default route (the one that is added by the MVC template) works fine to access an action on the DefaultController without having to specifying the controller name in the URL. I updated my question with more details about what is confusing me.